# "Pythagoras Theorem" - Why is "theorem" or "theory" used rather than "law" in mathematics?

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry

Why is Pythagoras Theorem a "theory" but not a "law"? I mean we use it many times in school and to build stairs etc. and it has been proven, however it is still called a theory.

What are the conventions for calling something a "theorem" or a "theory" rather than a "law" in mathematics?

Comment: It’s called a “theorem”, not a “theory” – just as you wrote yourself. I never saw anyone use the term “The Pythagoras Theory”. What do you mean by your question anyway?

Comment: a theorem is a law

Comment: we may ask Pythagoras about it? :D  joke

Comment: Ok... well someone explain the difference between theorem and theory?

Comment: because you are new,just for encourage +1,but please next time  ask specific questions

Comment: You are making the typical "theory"/"law" dichotomy mistake. The word "theory" is not used the way you are thinking in any of the sciences.

Comment: If I remember right, this problem is exacerbated by phrases like "law of gravity" and "theory of gravity."

Comment: I think $x+y=y+x$ is normally the commutative law, not the commutative theorem...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like you are using "theory" and "law" for things like "rules" as physicists sometimes do.

Traditionally mathematicians will call any significant result worth remembering a **theorem.** The Pythagorean Theorem is a archetypical example.

We use "law" sometimes too, but it's really the exception to the rule. (Like "Law of quadratic reciprocity.") There really isn't a standardized use of "law" in mathematics.

In mathematics, a **theory** is a large coherent group of results in the same field of study. It's used in the literal sense as "body of knowledge," not like "rule." So you can talk about "the theory of groups."

At any rate, <s>since there is no formal definition of "law" or "theory" in mathematics,</s> this is not so much a question about math as it is about language. You might try on english.SE.

---

English dictionary, I choose *you*!

> [Theory : 3.*Mathematics* . a body of principles, theorems, or the like, belonging to one subject: number theory.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/theory?s=t)
>
> [Theorem:  1.*Mathematics* . a theoretical proposition, statement, or formula embodying something to be proved from other propositions or formulas.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/theorem?s=t)

Comment: @datodatuashvili You flatterer, you :)

Comment: +1 but there *is* a formal definition of "theory" in mathematics, that is a set of propositions in some formal language, which is closed under deduction (from the rule of some logic): _Set theory_, the _thory of real-closed fields_, _Peano's theory_ etc.

Comment: @rewritten OK, I'm sure the mathematical-logic definition of "theory" can be applied, but I guess "formal" wasn't the right word. I guess I just meant that we are thinking of the regular English definition of theory, usually.

Comment: @rewritten And also I give exactly examples like that ("theory of groups")

Comment: +1 great answer, but would mentioning lemmas just confuse things? I just think it might round out the proof terminology.

Comment: @TimSeguine but then I'd have to go into Propositions, axioms and postulates too :(

Comment: @rschwieb okay, then don't wreck a great answer by that much surgery.